# Create Version Failed. Bad model detected with error: "Error loading the model" - AI Platform Prediction

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, google-prediction, google-ai-platform

I created a model through `AI Platform` UI that uses a global endpoint. I am trying to deploy a basic tensorflow 1.15.0 model I exported using the Saved Model builder. When I try to deploy this model I get a `Create Version Failed. Bad model detected with error: "Error loading the model"` error in the UI and the I see the following in the logs:

```
ERROR:root:Failed to import GA GRPC module. This is OK if the runtime version is 1.x

Failure: Could not reach metadata service: Internal Server Error.

ERROR:root:Command '['/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil', '-o', 'GoogleCompute:service_account=default', 'cp', '-R', 'gs://cml-365057443918-1608667078774578/models/xsqr_global/v6/7349456410861999293/model/*', '/tmp/model/0001']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

ERROR:root:Error loading model: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'

ERROR:root:Error loading the model
```

- **Framework/ML runtime version:** Tensorflow 1.15.0
- **Python:** 3.7.3

What is strange is that the `gcloud ai-platform local predict` works correctly with this exported model, *and* I can deploy this exact same model on a *regional* endpoint with no issues. It only gives this error if I try to use a global endpoint model. But I need the global endpoint because I plan on using a custom prediction routine (if I can get this basic model working first).

The logs seem to suggest an issue with copying the model from storage? I've tried giving various IAM roles additional viewer permissions, but I still get the same errors.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm facing with the same issue:
- Deploying a model with a global endpoint fails.
- Deploying a model with a regional endpoint succeeds, but it takes around 30mins to finish.

The interesting fact is that this happens in projects that I've created recently. The same procedure works well in a project that I created over a month ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the same issue as https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175316320

The comment in the issue says the fix is now rolling out.

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced the same error (ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error:  "Error loading the model") & for those who wants a summary:

The recommendation is to use n1* machine types (for example: n1-standard-4) via regional endpoints (for example: us-central1) instead of mls1* machines while deploying version. Also I made sure to mention the same region (us-central1) while creating the model itself using the below command, thereby resolving the above mentioned error.

> !gcloud ai-platform models create  $model_name 
> --region=$REGION